# Fitting an exponential approach/asymptotic power law in R/Python

Tags: python, r, curve-fitting

How can I fit my data to an asymptotic power law curve or an exponential approach curve in R or Python?

My data essentially shows that the the y-axis increases continuously but the delta (increase) decreases with increase in x.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: A standard (old-school) approach before you try to fit any curves is simply plot the data on a log (or semilog) axis(es). If the data is roughly linear, then you may have an exponential curve.

Answer (score 2):

Using Python, if you have numpy and scipy installed, you could use `curve_fit` of the`scipy` package. It takes a user-defined function and x- as well as y-values (x_values and y_values in the code), and returns the optimized parameters and the covariance of the parameters.

```
import numpy
import scipy

def exponential(x,a,b):
    return a*numpy.exp(b*x)

fit_data, covariance = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(exponential, x_values, y_values, (1.,1.))
```

This answer assumes you have your data as a one-dimensional numpy-array. You could easily convert your data into one of these, though.

The last argument contains starting values for your optimization. If you dont supply them, there might be problems in determining the number of parameters.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to import math, I corrected my answer in that way.